# How to grep in tail in several files

Tags: grep, logging, tail

I need to tail several files, and most info from them i removing (using grep). Now mine output dirty with file names. How i can remove them?

Short to problem:
`$ tail -F /log/rest_server*.log | egrep -v ' INFO (<some regext>)'`

return:

```
==> /log/rest_server_dbs0.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbs1.log <==
<some useful data1>

==> /log/rest_server_dbs0.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbs1.log <==
<some useful data2>

==> /log/rest_server_dbs0.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbs1.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbs0.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbs1.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbm0.log <==
<some useful data3>

==> /log/rest_server_dbs1.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbs0.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbs1.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbs0.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbs1.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbs0.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbs1.log <==

==> /log/rest_server_dbm0.log <==
<some useful data4>

==> /log/rest_server_dbs1.log <==
```

How I can remove this file names and black lines, if there is no data?

to make result

```
==> /log/rest_server_dbs1.log <==
<some useful data1>
<some useful data2>

==> /log/rest_server_dbm0.log <==
<some useful data3>
<some useful data4>
```

Comment: Please add some more details. I have no idea what you're asking. Maybe someone with the necessary knowledge could help you, but you are making your question hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands instead:

```
$ tail -F /log/rest_server*.log | sed -e "/^==>/d;/^$/d" | egrep -v ' INFO (<some regext>)'
```

The sed command removes the lines that start with "==>" and those that are empty;

Comment: with that i will get
`    <some useful data1>
    <some useful data2>
    <some useful data3>
    <some useful data4>
`
with loosing filenames, when i do get necessary info. I can do the same with only `grep`, without using `sed`